# Why can't I load byte A0h into z80 register?

Tags: assembly, z80

Is there some upper limit on how big a byte I can load into a z80 register?

Loading 9Fh works ok.
Attempting to load A0h results in an assembler error message.

I'm using the z80asm assembler on linux.

```
    $ cat load-test.asm
    ld a, 9Fh   ;ok
    ld b, 9Fh   ;ok

    ld a, A0h  ;error
    ld b, A0h  ;error

    $ z80asm load-test.asm -o load-test.bin
    load-test.asm:6: error: unable to resolve reference: A0h  ;error
    load-test.asm:6: error: unable to resolve reference: A0h  ;error
    *** 2 errors found ***
    $
```

Comment: Numbers have to start with a digit. Prefix with a zero if your hex starts with a letter, otherwise the assembler will think it's a symbol. TL;DR: use `0A0h`.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks Jester. Don't think I can mark a comment as providing the answer.

Comment: The duplicate is for masm/x86 but the answer applies.